# Convert this string to int list

Tags: python, string, list, integer, converters

so I have this code wrote in Python:

```
def gestionliste():

    liste_usager = input("Veuillez entrer la liste d'entiers:") #this ask the user to enter number(s) of his choice
    liste_usager=liste_usager.split(' ') 
    print(liste_usager)
```

But for example,if the user enter: 2 3 4, it will result as a string ["2","3","4"]. However,I want to make this list be an integer list like [2,3,4] and not string.How can I do/convert that? I tried that map thing but it didn't work for me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to convert the numbers into integers:

```
liste_usager = input("Veuillez entrer la liste d'entiers:")
liste_usager = [int(n) for n in liste_usager.split(' ')]
print(liste_usager)
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> liste_usager = input(":")
:2 3 4
>>> liste_usager = [int(n) for n in liste_usager.split(' ')]
>>> print(liste_usager)
[2, 3, 4]
>>> print(type(liste_usager[0]))
<class 'int'>
>>>
```

---

**Edit:**

The list comprehension is a one-line solution that is equivalent to doing:

```
liste_usager = input("Veuillez entrer la liste d'entiers:")

lst = []                           # A list to hold the numbers
for n in liste_usager.split(' '):  # For each item in liste_usager.split(' ')
    n = int(n)                     # Convert it into an integer
    lst.append(n)                  # And add it to lst

liste_usager = lst                 # Reassign liste_usager to lst

print(liste_usager)
```

Comment: @Jon_Computer - `x` (which I decided to change to `n`) will hold each item in the list returned by `liste_usager.split(' ')`.  See my edit for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use whitespace (including space character) as a delimiter. This will fail if any of the values the user enters cannot be converted to an integer, such as commas, fractional numbers, and letters.

```
map(int, liste_usager.split())
```

You may be better off with:

```
numbers = []
bad_values = []
for n in liste_usager.split():
    try:
        numbers.append(int(n))
    except ValueError, e:
        bad_values.append(n)
return numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use following:

```
  integers_list=map(int,liste_usager.split())
```

It will give u a list of integers in form `[1,2,3,4]` if input is `1 2 3 4` .